Is there any way to solve systems of coupled partial differential equations in Python?
I have the following set of partial differential equations:
$$\partial_t\langle a^\dagger a\rangle = -\kappa\langle a^\dagger a\rangle - 2N(g\text{Im}[C^{a+}] + g'\text{Im}[C^{a-}])$$
$$\partial_t\langle a a\rangle = -(2i\omega+\kappa)\langle a a\rangle -2iN(gC^{a-}+g'C^{a+})$$
$$\partial_t C^{a+} = -(i\omega+\frac{\kappa}{2}+\tilde{\Gamma})C^{a+} + i\omega_0C^{a+} - ig[(N-1)C^{+-} + \langle\sigma^z\rangle\langle a^\dagger a\rangle +\frac{1}{2}(1+\langle\sigma^z\rangle)] - ig'[(N-1)C^{++} + \langle\sigma^z\rangle\langle a a\rangle]$$
$$\partial_t C^{a-} = -(i\omega+\frac{\kappa}{2}+\tilde{\Gamma})C^{a-}-i\omega_0C^{a-}-ig[(N-1)(C^{++})^*-\langle\sigma^z\rangle\langle aa\rangle]-ig'[(N-1)C^{+-}-\langle\sigma^z\rangle\langle a^\dagger a\rangle +\frac{1}{2}(1-\langle\sigma^z\rangle)]$$
$$\partial_t C^{++} = 2i\omega_0C^{++}-2\tilde{\Gamma}C^{++}-2i\langle\sigma^z\rangle(g(C^{a-})^*+g'C^{a+})$$
$$\partial_t C^{+-} = -2\tilde{\Gamma}C^{+-}-2\langle\sigma^z\rangle(g\text{Im}[C^{a+}]-g'\text{Im}[C^{a-}])$$
$$\partial_t \langle\sigma^z\rangle = 4g\text{Im}[C^{a+}]-4g'\text{Im}[C^{a-}]-\Gamma_T\langle\sigma^z\rangle + \Gamma_\uparrow - \Gamma_\downarrow$$
These are coupled partial differential equations. I have searched for ways to solve this system numerically with python, but I only find packages to solve coupled ODEs or elliptic, hyperbolic, etc. PDEs. The only variables are the photonic and atomic operators, the rest are constants associated with the system losses. Do you know a way to solve the system numerically?

This site if for physics questions, not mathematics. Please try
mathematics.SE.

These are coupled partial differential equations. Why? There are only time derivatives.

What are you trying to solve for ?  What are the symbols ?  Are they constants ?  Functions of one or more variable ?

I forgot to give a little more context on the problem. I'm working with a model that combines properties of the Dicke model and the Tavis-Cummings model. These are the equations of motion for the second moments of photons, the radiation-matter correlations, matter-matter correlations, etc. The only thing I did to derive them was to use the fact that $$\langle \hat{A}\rangle = \text{Tr}[\rho A]$$. Furthermore $C^{a+}$ corresponds to the expected value of $$\langle a\sigma^+\rangle$$ and so on for the rest.

What I want is to solve these equations that only depend on t for the expectation values ​​of the second moments.
